# how to add it in single query without using inner joins?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT A.cl_id, A.cl_name, A.number_of_orders, B.Dispatch
FROM (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id, CL_Clients.cl_name,COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders
    FROM CL_Clients,CLOI_ClientOrderItems
    WHERE CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id
    ) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id,count(*) AS Dispatch
    FROM CLOI_ClientOrderItems,CL_Clients
    WHERE cloi_current_status = '12' 
        AND CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id, CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cloi_current_status
    ) B

    ON A.cl_id = B.cl_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.cl_id, A.cl_name, A.number_of_orders, B.Dispatch
FROM (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id, CL_Clients.cl_name,COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders
    FROM CL_Clients,CLOI_ClientOrderItems
    WHERE CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id
    ) A
, (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id,count(*) AS Dispatch
    FROM CLOI_ClientOrderItems,CL_Clients
    WHERE cloi_current_status = '12' 
        AND CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id, CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cloi_current_status
    ) B

WHERE A.cl_id = B.cl_id
```

Comment: in my first query result i have 574 row and 2nd query i have 149 if i run this query it will show only 149 but 1st query row not displaying so i need to display all 574 row with 2nd query result

Comment: Then replace INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN (should be outer join to reflect all rows from q1)

Comment: how it work show using my query and in 2nd query i am checking through where condition i have many where con how can i put

Comment: how to implement it in my query using left join

Comment: pls reply for that query